# Handling 'Variable not found' in a tokenised job step

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, powershell

I have an Agent job which is usually triggered by a WMI event.  The job has a token within it, which automatically takes a value from the WMI event and substitutes it into the step's Powershell code, e.g.:

```
$alert_wmi_state = '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(WMI(State)))';
```

The SQL Agent is configured with the *Replace tokens for all job responses to alerts* setting checked so, when the WMI event triggers, the substitution happens fine, and the code that is run is:

```
$alert_wmi_state = '7';
```

However, there is the possibility that this job could be run manually (i.e. right-click, Start Job at step...) and I would like my step code to handle this gracefully, so I have this logic further in my step:

```
if ($alert_wmi_state -eq ('$' + '(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(WMI(State)))')) {
    ...
}
```

...the theory being that, splitting `$` from `(ESCAPE_SQUOTE...` would reasonably mean that this is not recognised as a token, and so does not get substituted, so the test would read literally:

```
if ($alert_wmi_state -eq '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(WMI(State)))') {
    ...
}
```

However, when running the job manually, the SQL Agent always errors out at the step (regardless if it's configured as a *CmdExec* job step type or a *PowerShell* job step type) before any of my code is run, with the error `Variable WMI(State) not found`.

My guess is that this is because the substitution of `ESCAPE_SQUOTE` happens *before* the step code is actually parsed/loaded, so the Agent never runs the step.

I expect I could have two steps, one with the token and one without, and have the failure action of the tokenised one start the non-tokenised one, but that duplication of step code is not desirable.

So, my question is, is there any way to gracefully handle the non-existence of a step token within the step code?

Answer (score 1):

Would using a [PowerShell here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-5.1) in your script prevent the need for `ESCAPE_SQUOTE`?

```
$alert_wmi_state = @'
$(WMI(State))
'@
```

That should at least let you determine if the problem is with `ESCAPE_SQUOTE` throwing an error or if it's SQL Agent's token parser itself that's complaining.

As long a the SQL Agent doesn't literally begin with `'@` you should be fine.  If it *does* begin with `'@`, you can fix that easily:

```
$alert_wmi_state = @'
_$(WMI(State))
'@.Substring(1)
```

Note that you typically want to use `@'...'@` and not `@"..."@` since the latter is still evaluated by PowerShell like a double quoted string.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  The problem is not with Powershell's interpretation of the literal, but that the SQL Agent substitutes the literal `$ESCAPE_SQUOTE(WMI(State))` with a value that it determines *before the step starts* but, if that value does not exist for any reason, it won't even start the step.  This leaves no way to guard against this value not existing from *within* the step code.